# Error in combining multiple control flow statements in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am struggling with combining multiple conditionals in R. I was able to make it work for the single conditional but i keep getting error with multiple conditionals. Here is a example..

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
    library(getopt)
    args<-commandArgs(TRUE)    
    options<-matrix(c('lincRNA',    'l',    1,  "character",
                          'lincRNAbed', 'b',    1,  "character",
                          'overlap',    'v',    2,  "character",
                          'tss',        't',    2,  "character",
                          'help',       'h',    0,  "logical"),
                           ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

ret.opts<-getopt(options,args)

# No TSS file here
if(is.null(ret.opts$tss)) {
    # All lincRNA's
    fastaFile <- readDNAStringSet(ret.opts$lincRNA)
    lincRNA_ID = names(fastaFile)
    sequence = paste(fastaFile)
    size = width(fastaFile)
    df <- data.frame(lincRNA_ID, size)
# No overlap file here
} else if(is.null(ret.opts$overlap)) {
    # All lincRNA's
    fastaFile <- readDNAStringSet(ret.opts$lincRNA)
    lincRNA_ID = names(fastaFile)
    sequence = paste(fastaFile)
    size = width(fastaFile)
    df <- data.frame(lincRNA_ID, size)
# Both not present
} else if(is.null(ret.opts$tss) && is.null(ret.opts$overlap)){
  # All lincRNA's
  fastaFile <- readDNAStringSet(ret.opts$lincRNA)
  lincRNA_ID = names(fastaFile)
  sequence = paste(fastaFile)
  size = width(fastaFile)
  df <- data.frame(lincRNA_ID, size)
# Both present
} else {
    # All lincRNA's
    fastaFile <- readDNAStringSet(ret.opts$lincRNA)
    lincRNA_ID = names(fastaFile)
    sequence = paste(fastaFile)
    size = width(fastaFile)
    df <- data.frame(lincRNA_ID, size)
}
```

It works for conditionals 1,2 and 4. Here is an example

```
Rscript test.R --lincRNA lincRNAs.fa --lincRNAbed lincRNAs.bed --tss lincRNAs.with.CAGE.support.annotated.fa
Rscript test.R --lincRNA lincRNAs.fa --lincRNAbed lincRNAs.bed --overlap lincRNAs.overlapping.known.lincs.fa
Rscript test.R --lincRNA lincRNAs.fa --lincRNAbed lincRNAs.bed --overlap lincRNAs.overlapping.known.lincs.fa --tss lincRNAs.with.CAGE.support.annotated.fa
```

But i when run it with multiple conditional, i keep getting error.

```
Rscript test.R --lincRNA lincRNAs.fa --lincRNAbed lincRNAs.bed
Error in .normarg_input_filepath(filepath) : 
              'filepath' must be a character vector with no NAs
            Calls: readDNAStringSet ... fasta.index -> <Anonymous> -> .normarg_input_filepath
            Execution halted
```

I know the syntax for multiple conditionals is wrong but i can't figure out what it is. I tried different ways but without success.

Comment: What is `getopt`? And `args`? Please, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I just edited it. Let me know if it still doesn't make sense

Comment: It looks like the code is failing in an entirely different part. As nicola asked: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem isn't the control flow statements ("conditionals") it's what the error says -- the file path

Comment: I again edited the post to make it more legible.

Comment: @Hack-R but it works for all three conditions and they all share the same paths..